# Application_Start exceptions handling in IIS7 environment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I'm building ASP.NET MVC3 application and in addition to the standard MVC exception handling mechanism I want to show a static html error page when something went wrong in Application_Start and an unhandled exception is thrown over there.

I've just added

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.htm">
```

and expected redirection to Error.htm in all "error" cases. It works properly with Visual Studio Development Server but doesn't work at all with IIS7 (I see the standard yellow screen with "To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on..."). It seems that when exception is thrown in Application_Start ASP.NET redirects to Error.htm and at this moment IIS calls Application_Start method again where the same exception throws again aaaand welcome to the infinite loop.

What are the options to resolve this problem? Can it be done without changing IIS settings? If not, how it should be done properly on the IIS side?

Answer (score -1):

Better late than never. This is the standard way of handling errors:

testproject\Views\Shared\Error.cshtml

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}
<p>an error occurred</p><br />
<p>Try again.Go on this <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">link</a></p>
```

testproject\Controllers\TestController.cs

```
namespace testproject.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {}
}
```

testproject\Web.config

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml" />   
</system.web>
```